# jquery clone select doesnt keep value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a feildset then submit the contents of inputs and selects using serialize. It is working properly however select doesn't keep its value. I have tried several methods I have found but nothing seems to work. Here is how I am cloning and setting the current data.

How can I keep the value of select when cloning?

```
 $('body').append('<form id="form-to-submit" style="visibility:hidden;"></form>');  
var fieldsetName = $this.parents('.fieldsetwrapper');  
$('#form-to-submit').html($(fieldsetName).clone());  
var data = $('#form-to-submit').serialize();
```

Comment: Instead of cloning the entire fieldset, why not just serialize the data from the fieldset as a JS object when you want, and use that object to restore later (if that's what you're after). Or have I misunderstood the reason that you are cloning?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.html()` with `.clone()`. Clone gives elements, while `.html()` expects a string. Use the elements directly: `$('#form-to-submit').empty().append($(fieldsetName).clone());`

Comment: same issue is on prototype library

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `option` element maintains its current selectedness with the `selected` javascript property (not to be confused with the `selected` attribute, which corresponds to *default* selectedness).

Since jQuery's `clone` doesn't  clone the current selectedness (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1294) , you'll have to do it manually:

```
$('#form-to-submit').html($(fieldsetName).clone());
$('#form-to-submit select').val($('.fieldsetwrapper select').val());
```

Comment: Hi, this is a really interesting solution, i didn't know that jQuery could find alone where to place the selected values.
Is there a way to use this form an entire form and not only select elements ?
Do you know a link that speak about this ? Thanks

Comment: I found that this solution didn't work for multiple select menus if they had different direct parents. Instead I had to loop over "each" of the selects and match it with the corresponding select in the original with the ".eq" method. Just a quick note for anyone skimming through! :)

Comment: @Casey, I whish you had elaborated with a piece of code :) You'd still have to get the index of the original select right? Or is there another magic function that does this? :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set the value of the new `select` element to the value of the old one:

```
$('#form-to-submit select').val($('.fieldsetwrapper select').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using

```
$('<form></form>').html($('.myDiv').clone())
```

and fixed the issue by adding another form to the markup

```
$('.myForm').serialize()
```