# Clone all form to another different one hiding the elements and submit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I was handling only one form but I'm having the need to use another different one (with all same inputs on it), because when submitting, depending on some action it will execute different stuff, the original form is

`<form id="card-form"> 
Some inputs are generated dynamically with "append"...
</form>`

I want to pass all inputs to another one with id "reservation", but the user must not see it, it needs to be able to submit to send request to server (not via ajax).

I was trying for instance, this:

```
var form1 = $('#card-form'), 
  form2 = $('#form2');  

$('#copy').click(function(){
 $(':input[name]', form2).val(function(){
    return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
 });
});
```

But the appended inputs aren't being copied. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you probably want to use https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: will it copy the appended elements?

Comment: yep. if I understood you correct

Comment: please check my answer. you can also clone events with `deepWithDataAndEvents` param provided (if you have any validators or something like this)

Comment: @llamerr It works, but what can I do to submit that form not with ajax, with a button that the user won't notice the difference that he is submitting a hidden form

Comment: @llamerr The hidden form has the "action" property and method specified, they will go to another php file, but not with ajax, it needs to reload the page

Comment: so first form must be submitted with ajax, and when ajax finishes, you need to submit second form using `form.submit()` which will reload page, right?

Comment: The form is about a hotel reservation with web services, but there are two steps first, those are being executed with ajax using the same form with id "card-form", after those steps are completed, I need to submit the third step which includes payment information, but the payment runs with a plugin called "conekta", which doesn't support ajax, so I need to submit all the values of "card-form" without ajax.

Comment: check this method of form https://api.jquery.com/submit/ you need to interrupt submit by `preventDefault()` and send your ajax manually for first form, then just allow sending of second form - https://jsfiddle.net/La21o6on/2/

Comment: @llamerr I just noticed one more thing, the "select" tag values are not being cloned, do you know the reason?

Comment: @llamerr t is being cloned, but it clones with the default value, not with the selected one

Comment: seems there's a bug for it in jquery and you need to do it manually - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599773/jquery-clone-select-doesnt-keep-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/La21o6on/1/

```
var form1 = $('#card-form'),
    form2 = $('#form2');

$('#copy').click(function(){
    $(':input[name]', form1).each(function(){
        var n = $(this).clone();
        n.attr('id',n.attr('id')+"form2").appendTo( form2 );
    })
});
```

I'm clonning each input into `n` var and renaming it's id here.

First problem I'm seeing is you selecting elements inside empty new form - `$(':input[name]', form2)`, you need to pass old form instead. Other one - I'm not sure why you using `val` for that? `this` links to current element in jquery code.