# Replicate HTML source of a DOM element in current state

Tags: javascript, html

On my page there are a few `<select>` html elements, each of them with multiple `<option>` values. I would like the same `<select>` elements to be used in a MapBox description toolkit, which expects me to pass a HTML source into [its setHTML method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Popup#setHTML).

The simple way I do it now is:

```
  var tableOption = document.getElementById(selectId);
  var html = tableOption.innerHTML;
  return "<select>" + html + "</select>";
```

This works, however it has a drawback of passing the original html source, therefore it does not reflect which option is selected right now. I know I can get currently selected option with [value](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp) or [selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp), and it should be possible to parse the HTML I have obtained and remove and add `selected` property to a corresponding node in JS, however this seems a bit complicated.

Is there some easier way how to get a HTML source which could be used to construct a copy of a `select` element with the exact selection state it has now?

I would prefer a solution without jQuery if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery clone select doesnt keep value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599773/jquery-clone-select-doesnt-keep-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just wrap your `select` in another element. Then you'd be able to select it by id, get the parent node, then the parent node's `innerHTML`. If you want to show which `option` is currently selected, you can place the `selected` attribute on it.

```js
document.getElementById('selectId').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var opts = this.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++)
        opts[i].removeAttribute('selected');
    this.querySelector('option:checked').setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    console.log(this.parentNode.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select id="selectId">
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no problem with obtaining innerHTML, by problem is innerHTML seems to be the original page source, it does not seem to reflect the current selection. Am I wrong?

Comment: It will be the HTML of all descendant elements corresponding to the element you use `innerHTML` on. In this case, we end up on the `div` through `parentNode`, thus `innerHTML` gives the HTML inside the `div`. This means that your wrapper must **only** contain the select and its options. Notice my example gives the HTML for the `select` and `option`s, but not the `div`.

Comment: @Suma I think I understand what you mean now. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Using `outerHTML` instead of `this.parentNode.innerHTML` would prevent grabbing siblings of the select. using jQuery might allow for bulk removing of the selected attribute

Comment: @Brian I wasn't even aware of `outerHTML`, but you're right. This only works if the `select` is the only thing being wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone the element and then set the selectedIndex - things like event handlers probably wouldn't be copied though

I realize you asked for a simpler solution but I can't think of one much simpler considering it's only 4 lines
Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s8mb0mxp/2/

HTML

```
<select id="original">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
</select>

<button>
Clone
</button>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var $original = $('#original'); 
    var el = $original.clone(); // Clone the object
    $('#target').append(el) // Attach the new object to an element
    el.find('option')[$original[0].selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected', 'selected')
    console.log(el[0].outerHTML)
});
```

Comment: I also tried clone() with both `withDataAndEvents` and `deepWithDataAndEvents` and neither copies selectedIndex if selected by the user. Also tried passing the node to `Object.create` and `document.createElement` as well as calling `$original.cloneNode` with no luck, wonder if it's because the parent node is created first then options individually which would invalidate selectedIndex

Comment: Where do I get the desired HTML source with this solution? (I can see that in Gavin's answer, but not in this).

Comment: The HTML I used is included in the answer - I just used a select with it's id set to original and a div with id target which is where the cloned selects are placed. The fiddle also has a working example

Comment: I do not mean your HTML, what I mean my question is about I need to get  a HTML string (this is a requirement of the library I am using). Your solution seems to be cloning DOM, and I do not see any point where I would get the HTML string I need. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I missed that requirement - I've updated the answer to reflect this - jQuery doesn't neaten it up much. Gavin's answer is better for the most part probably. Only difference that might be worth borrowing is my edit uses `outerHTML` to retrieve the markup directly as opposed to via the parent nodes innerHTML (which might grab siblings)